# What do the words "tunc tantum" mean together?

Tags: meaning, christianity, adverb

Pope Francis [tweeted on September 21st](https://twitter.com/Pontifex_ln/status/778556988686934016),

> Sermonem confero cum aliquo sincerum tunc tantum agnosco illum esse donum Dei mihique aliquid pretiosum dicturum.

Here is my translation. (Credits to [Keith Massey](http://aplaceofbrightness.blogspot.com/2016/09/learning-latin-with-pope-francis_21.html) for his help.)

> I engage in a sincere dialogue with someone only after I recognize that person is a gift of God and about to say something precious to me.

My confusion is with the phrase *tunc tantum*. I recognize *tantum* as an adverb meaning "only", but I'm unsure of how to translate *tunc* alongside of it. I am accustomed to *tunc* meaning "then", but in this case could it possibly mean "when"?

I checked the Lewis and Short dictionary, and couldn't find this sense of *tunc*. But it seems to be the most appropriate translation. Is going from "then" to "when" not such a big stretch after all — am I merely nitpicking? Or are there dictionaries that document this sense of *tunc* after all?

Comment: How often in Petrarca or Boccaccio do we see these “odd” uses that may be of era or locale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This usage strikes me as strange**, so I will make the case for that. I would be happy if another answer corrects me!

There are 12 matches in the [Packhum *corpus* database for *tunc tantum*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23tunc+tantum%23): there are no cases of it being a temporal/conditional conjunction. The vast majority are coordinated with temporal conjuctions (*tunc...cum / ubi / dum*), one is used alone to mean "only at this time," and a final one is used with *quanto + comparative adjective* to mean "this only occurs the more X something is."

The [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtunc) entry does list some conditional meanings of *tunc*, but it is always used as an adverb. An example:

> cuperem tecum communicare tam subitam mutationem mei: **tunc** amicitiae nostrae certiorem fiduciam habere coepissem. (Sen. Ep. 6, 2)
>
> *I would like to discuss with you such a sudden change in me: **then** I would begin to have stronger confidence in our friendship.*

Conclusion: ***tunc* can only be used as an adverb**

The current usage is different though: it essentially functions as a restrictive particle like *dummodo*, *dumtaxat*, or *quatenus*.

A simplified sentence that illustrates this use would be:

> Bonus sum **tunc tantum** fidelis sum.
>
> *I am good **only when (?)** I am faithful.*

Another points that makes me question this usage is that **I expect the subjunctive for this kind of qualification**, whereas *agnosco* is indicative. The other restrictive conjunctions mentioned above take the subjunctive as well, which seems to confirm this gut feeling.

Again, I am happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: For the record: [Fr. Daniel Gallagher](http://www.npr.org/2014/03/28/295851405/monsignor-brings-pope-s-tweets-to-the-world-in-latin) is generally responsible for these translations and is (otherwise...?) an excellent Latinist.

Comment: I guess that this is medieval Latin, which so often ignores classical syntax, just so long as the meaning is clear. Indicative "agnosco" then would not be unexpected, but I don't think we can demand the same standards here as we would do of Cicero or Caesar !

Comment: Great points — it does make sense that *tunc* is not being used as an adverb (as it is joining two clauses) in which case it is peculiar.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with restrictive particles, but to me the part of speech for *tunc* seems to be a conjunction. Can a particle be a conjunction? Is that the case here?

Comment: @TomCotton I've read a lot of medieval Latin and this still strikes me as off: Medieval Latin has idiosyncracies that are well-studied, but it isn't a catch-all umbrella for solecisms. Also, since Erasmus the growing trend of Latinists of this kind is to consciously emulate classical patterns wherever possible: the acc. + inf. construction (instead of *quia*) seems to confirm that.

Comment: @ktm5124 I just blindly used L&S's ["restrictive particle" phrase](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddum), but yes I would have said "conjunction."

Comment: It strikes me as "off", too. In addition to that, I hope you'd agree with me that we shouldn't accept every old text as unimpeachable (as so many people seem to do) but ought to strive for the real  meaning without getting upset by any less-than-perfect grammar.

Comment: @brianpck I see, thanks. I'm glad I'm not the only one who finds it strange.

Comment: I agree. And I have seen other errors in publications from the Vatican. It appears the Pope is not quite infallible.

Comment: @Cerberus Well, if you call this a formally defined matter of faith and morals, then sure :) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_infallibility))

Comment: @brianpck: I should think it a deterioration of morals when his Latin falters!

Answer (score 4):

As it is virtually impossible to draw up a complete list of every adverbial phrase, the rarer ones are often omitted from dictionaries, this perhaps being justified as *hapax legomenon*. It's sometimes necessary to use a bit of imagination, as many scholiasts or commentators seem to have done quite often in such circumstances.

I think here that *tunc tantum* simply means "only then", but with a little licence you might express it as, say, "at which point" - or construe into something else which might fit the case. Provided that it agrees with its context, you could even translate as "It is only when I'm engaged in serious dialogue with anyone that I can see that he is a gift, etc."

Comment: I don't think it's terribly meaningful to talk about a grammatical *hapax legomenon* in the context of something that was just written on Twitter... :)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I wasn't referring to the tweet but wished to suggest that the compilers of dictionaries, for reasons of space, are liable to exclude a hapax legomenon that they consider of little significance.

Comment: Got it. I still think you are extending a little too much latitude to a Latin tweet by suggesting that he is using a construction that has never been recorded before.

Comment: *Cringes and backs into corner slowly* I think this might be a duplicate ...*closes eyes*